# Power BI Count not working correctly for SamePeriodLastYear with slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a table as follows with three years of data. I need to count the Incidents for current year and last year. It works fine until I use a slicer  of Incident Classification. The data is in a star schema.

```
Incident ID,   Incident Classification,   Date

999-A,         Class A,                   2018-01-06

923-C,         Class A,                   2018-05-07

399-A,         Class B,                   2017-02-06

923-C,         Class A,                   2017-09-07
```

My current vs prior year total count is coming out correctly (i.e., 2 for 2018 and 2 for 2017). However, when I add the slicer (or filter it) using Incident Classification Class A, the number for prior year is much higher (I have around 2500 rows in the table). The correct answer should be 2 for 2018 and 1 for 2017.

My Measures are defined as:

```
CY Incident Count = CALCULATE(COUNT(Fact_All_Incidents[Incident_ID]))

PY Incident Count = CALCULATE(COUNT(Fact_All_Incidents[Incident_ID]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(vDim_Date[Full_Date]), ALL(Fact_All_Incidents))
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue. I changed the Prior Year measure to the following and that worked:

PY Incident Count = CALCULATE(COUNT(Fact_All_Incidents[Incident_ID]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(vDim_Date[Full_Date])).

Basically I took out the ALL(Fact_All_Incidents) filter from the measure.

Answer (score 0):

Use distinctcount on Incident ID

Try this:

```
PY Incident Count = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Fact_All_Incidents[Incident_ID]), FILTER('Fact_All_Incidents', year(Fact_All_Incidents[date]) = 2017))
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am unable to use what you suggested since I am using an int Date_Key (surrogate key) in my fact table. However, I am able to do it in a different way and I do get the correct answer for 2017. The issue is that then the 2016 number is incorrect. So basically, the PY is not working as required. (To get the answer for 2017, I just use Incident Count = CALCULATE(COUNT(Fact_All_Incidents[Incident_ID])) and filter the report for 2017 in the slicer.. My Incident ID's are unique so I don't think I need to use DistinctCount.).

Comment: OK, I am glad you were able to find a solution. Just an FYI, you don't need to wrap your Count with a Calculate unless you specify some type of filter/expression.